# Referencia campo de details desde el footer

Tags: report, pentaho

en el details de mi report, tengo un number field que me toma un valor dependiendo de un campo del data source.  Me gustaría poder desde fuera del detail poder hacer una referencia a ese valor para después hacer una gráfica.

Ejemplo.

```
Header
   Nombre   Valor 1  Valor 2

Detail
   Prueba   1         44
   Otra     44         3
            45        47  //Number Filed Sum Colum
   Footer
---------------------------------------------------------
            45        47    Desde el footer quiero acceder a esos campos sumados
```

Comment: Una pregunta @LorenzoMartin, ¿estas usando el Report Designer?

Comment: Si, es el que uso